# Translating「メーラーの設定によってクリックのみでは正しく開けない場合があります」

Tags: grammar, translation, words, verbs, expressions

Here is the phrase:

> メーラーの設定によってクリックのみでは正しく開けない場合があります

The expressions that have me stuck are:

1. みで - I'm not sure what this expression could be... is it some kind of modifier possibly or is it some form of 見る
2. 正しく開けない - I get that this is a compound verb of sorts with the words 正しい and 開ける. I know what each of the words mean individually, but I can't figure out what word they are expressing together.
3. メーラー - I tried sounding it out and at first I thought it was 'mirror', but it isn't. I can't think of an English equivalent. Is it just a emoji?

I know this forum is for inquiries in 'proficient' Japanese and that my question might be too obvious, but I didn't know where else to go to ask for help. I apologize if my post is inappropriate.

P.S. My Japanese proficiency is BEGINNER.

Comment: Would be nice if you can make title more concise

Comment: Look up のみ (the particle, not the noun).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. 「みで」is not the expression your looking for. That part of the sentence should be parsed クリック **のみ** では - "by **only** clicking"
2. You're on the right track. By changing 正し**い** to 正し**く** it becomes an adverb, so you get 正し**く**開けない - "can't correct**ly** open"
3. メーラー is probably "mailer", perhaps you mistook the first kana?

Answer (score 2):

I take your quote. ”メーラーの設定によってクリックのみでは正しく開けない場合があります” as;

Depending on the setting on the part of the mail sender, there is a case that you cannot open the file simply by clicking (the mouse).

1.“みで” should be “のみで” meaning “only by (clicking).

2."正しく開けない" means “unable to open (the file) properly.

3. "メーラー" should be “mailer / mail sender.”